# How do I filter a json print to only spit out certain values

Tags: python, json, python-requests

Code:

```
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
print(json.dumps(response.json(), indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
    "errors": [],
    "result": [
        {
            "hex": "18:93:d7",
            "b16": "1893d7",
            "name": "texas instruments",
            "address": "12500 ti blvd dallas tx 75243 us"
        }
    ]
}
```

My Goal:

I want to only print hex, name & address. i want to prettify it aswell but before i do that i need to filter the output

Comment: response.json() is just an iterated list-dict object; you can simply delete the "b16" entry of the "result" entry of response.json(), which is an entry in a dictionary in a dictionary.

Comment: `data = response.json()` and `print( data["result"][0]["hex"] )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
for i in 'hex', 'name', 'address':
    print(i.capitalize(), response.json()['result'][0][i])
```

and you'll get:

```
Hex 18:93:d7
Name texas instruments
Address 12500 ti blvd dallas tx 75243 us
```

Comment: its telling me that result isnt identified im not sure why, ill be right back

Comment: Using the json you provided, it works well on my computer. Check if the return value is the same as you posted.

Comment: never mind i was being stupid, i forgot my api key lol. everything is working, much appreciated friend

Comment: It's my pleasure. 

Comment: im learning as i go to be honest, i noticed that you added a i.capitalize to capitialize the result. is it possible to do the same to add a suffix of ":"

Comment: f-string is a good tool. Note that you should use different quotation marks. `print(f"{i.capitalize()}: {r['result'][0][i]}")`